# python - breaking down a relative path

Tags: python, path

I am trying to create some directories on a remote machine using ssh and paramiko. Say I have a path relative like

```
path = 'Downloads/python/module/class/file.py'
```

Can I use os.path (or something else) to get output as

```
Downloads
Downloads/python
Downloads/python/module
Downloads/python/module/class
```

I could manipulate the string, but that never feels clean when working with file paths and won't be cross platform. If I get the output as mentioned, I can create the required directories in order.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `os.makedirs(path)` to create all non-existing paths recursively, so no need to fiddle with the string.

Comment: I'm doing this over an ssh tunnel using sftp with paramiko. I don't think I have this option

Comment: You should update your question with details about what you are actually trying to do instead of your attempted solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I can just use `os.path.dirname`

```
l = []
while path:
    l.append(path)
    path = os.path.dirname(path)
    if path == os.sep:
        path=''
print l
```

I can then pop out what I need